# c++: Pass pointer to object within object as argument

Tags: c++, arduino

The code is for Arduino if that matters...

```
class Xbee{
  public:
    Xbee(SoftwareSerial *xbeeSerial, SoftwareSerial *debugPrinter);
};

class localXbee : public Xbee{
  public:
    localXbee(SoftwareSerial *xbeeSerial, SoftwareSerial *debugPrinter);
    void addRemoteXbee(remoteXbee *newBee, byte index);
};

class remoteXbee : public Xbee{
  public:
    remoteXbee(long AddressLSB, SoftwareSerial *xbeeSerial, SoftwareSerial *debugPrinter);

class xbeeThermostat{
  public:
    xbeeThermostat(long AddressLSB, SoftwareSerial *xbeeSerial, SoftwareSerial *debugPrinter);
    remoteXbee thermoBee;
};
```

So how do I call the addRemoteXbee function in the localXbee object when the remoteXbee object is inside the xbeeThermostat object?

```
localXbee coordinator(&xbeeSerial, &debugPrinter);
xbeeThermostat thermostat(0x40BE4864, &xbeeSerial, &debugPrinter);

void setup(){
    coordinator.addRemoteXbee(&xbeeThermostat.thermoBee,0);
}
```

When trying to compile I get the error message:
expected primary-expression before '.' token

Comment: You've declared a function `dog::findthefood`, but never _defined_ it.

Comment: With definitions, and fixed return for `main`, it compiles: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48e39729f195e689)

Comment: The code you provided compiles just fine (in order to link you need to provide bodies for the functions, as ForceBru points out).  Please show code that reproduces your problem, and include the actual error message you're seeing.

Comment: "Does not work" is the least useful problem description in the world.

Comment: Ok, got it. I'm new to the forum, tried adding the code as comment but ran out of charactes, so I edited the original post instead...

Comment: ... I go cross eyed whenever I see posts like this, so I thought the simplified dog food example would be easier to understand and generate more answers. Crossing my fingers that this will help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the obvious bug:

```
void setup(){
    coordinator.addRemoteXbee(&thermostat.thermoBee,0);
}
```

Thanks for the help guys :)